# rPython crashes when I try to load a .py file with pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpython

`rpytester.r` and contains the following lines

```
library(rPython)
python.load("model.py")
python.call("printme", "asdf")
```

`model.py` contains the following line:

```
def printme( str ):
    "This prints a passed string into this function"
    return str
```

When I execute the `rpytester.r` by putting

```
import pandas as pd
```

in the first line of `model.py`, r session crashes and the following error message shows up.

[image]

Otherwise the programs work as expected.

The error message in textual format is:

```
r6034 an application has made an attempt to load the c runtime incorrectly
```

I have installed Anaconda 2 for python 2.7.13, and R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06).

I have looked at this post: [Runtime error R6034 in embedded Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552348/runtime-error-r6034-in-embedded-python-application/14680947#14680947)
But even after removing the  `msvcr90.dll`, the error persists. (Though, I do not know how to set the path since it is in the Anaconda 2 folder).

Comment: Side note: Post the error as text as well and not just a picture: But what version of python, operating system, etc? You may want to uninstall/reinstall pandas. It's not surprising that a `c++` error would show as pandas is often. from the wiki: [The library is highly optimized for performance, with critical code paths written in Cython or C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software))

Comment: @MattR Thanks for the suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is somehow solved when I uninstalled Anaconda 2 and installed Python from the official website.