# How to resolve Pymongo Runtime Error R6034 in Houdini

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, houdini

I'm working at a visual effects studio in which we use MongoDB/pymongo for our asset management. Our studio is using the SideFX software Houdini.
So far MongoDB has been a pleasure to work with in terms of programming, however whenever we connect to the MongoDB via pymongo from within Houdini, we're getting the following error:

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library - Runtime Error! 
Program: C:\houdini\17.5.293\bin\houdini.exe
R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[image]

This error occurs everytime when we import pymongo for the very first time, i.e. in a Python shell within Houdini, which is using Python 2.7. Once we click 'OK' on the error popup (it appears twice after clicking OK for the first time), the error disappears and we're able to connect successfully to the database.
The SideFX support team suggested that pymongo wasn't compiled with Visual Studio 2017, which is the compiler SideFX is using for their software.

Now we've been trying to debug this for a while now to no avail. Here's a rundown of what we tried:

1. update Windows10 to the latest and greatest
2. updating pymongo from 3.5.1 to 3.9.0
3. launching Houdini from different builds (16.5, 17.0, 17.5), we get the error in every version.(We're launching a vanilla Houdini session without any 'PYTHONPATH' or 'PATH' environment variables set)
4. interestingly enough my colleague imported pymongo into Houdini successfully on his private laptop last night without any errors occurring which leads me to believe that the error might be related to our system settings possibly?

I would love to find out how to get rid of this error message because it is really messing with our current pipeline. Any suggestions/help is welcome and much appreciated.
Please let me know if you need any additional information in order to debug this matter.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Manu

Answer (score 0):

This post here helped me to resolve my issue:
[Runtime error R6034 in embedded Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552348/runtime-error-r6034-in-embedded-python-application)

What happened is that we have a Python 2.7 install located at C:\Python27 which is being added as an environment variable 'path' in Windows.
Using the Process Explorer, I learned that this folder contains the file 'msvcr90.dll' which is conflicting with Houdini, since Houdini comes with its own Python installation that doesn't contain this dll file.
The solution is simple. When launching Houdini in a custom environment, strip the C:\Python27 from the 'path' environment variable so Houdini only fires up its own Python interpreter.